# Regular expression to filter filenames in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have strings that represent file paths. Something like this.

```
folder1/folderA/file1.flv  
folder2/folderB/file1.mp4  
folder3/folderC/file1.jpg
```

I am trying to write an expression that basically matches against a list of valid extensions such as `.flv`, `.mp4`, `.flv`

I am sure I am way off here but here's what I have `.[(\.flv/)|(\.wmv/)|(\.mp4)]`
comical, I'm sure... but hopefully shows the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret it correctly, you probably just want something like:

```
/[.](flv|mp4|wmv)$/
```

The `$` ensures that it matches at the end of the string/filename. The alternatives are listed in the parens, and the `[.]` is just a nicer notation for `\.`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to a regex, you could use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) which will reliably get you the file extension from a path.

```
$allowed_extensions = array("flv", "mp4", "mpeg"); # note: all lowercase

$ext = pathinfo("/folder1/folderA/file1.flv", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

# Search array of allowed extensions
if (in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_extensions))
 echo "Okay";
else
 echo "Fail";
```

Comment: I am passing the regex as a string to another function; otherwise, I'm with you! http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_list (for more reference)

Comment: @Ecro ah, fair enough. It won't work in that case. Maybe add that info to the question to get some more answers

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "folder1/folderA/file1.jpg";
$found =  preg_match("/[.]+(jpg|flv)$/", $str, $returns);
print_r ($returns);
```